# Creating iterable list of register in embedded C

Tags: c, list, struct, embedded

I have been programming with python java and c++, which all have list objects predefined. I'm now working on a microcontroller in C embedded, but objects such as lists and functions such as printf simply don't exist.

What I am trying to do is the following. I have multiple registers which I attach to defines. I want to put all my defines in a list I can access.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xc.h>

#define KP_ROW1     LATBbits.LATB0
#define KP_ROW2     LATBbits.LATB1
#define KP_ROW3     LATBbits.LATB2
#define KP_ROW4     LATBbits.LATB3
#define KP_COL1     LATBbits.LATB4
#define KP_COL2     LATBbits.LATB5
#define KP_COL3     LATBbits.LATB6
#define KP_COL4     LATBbits.LATB7

KP_ROW = [KP_ROW1, KP_ROW2, KP_ROW3, KP_ROW4]; //error on this line
KP_COL = [KP_COL1, KP_COL2, KP_COL3, KP_COL4]; //error

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if (KP_COL[i] == 1){return 1;}
    }
```

Since I have no previous experience in C embedded, I assumed that google could help me, but it seems that all the solutions I find need the good understanding of struct and the fabrication of really complex functions.

The reasons for this is that I will have maybe 100 pins and I don,t want to make "if" statements for each, I want to iterate throughout a list. I'm using a PIC18F with the XC8 compiler.

I'm asking for advice. How would you do it? Is there a faster, simpler way than making your own list class?

Comment: So can you give us the error messages that the compiler emits for the lines in error? They look like syntax errors, which if you have some experience in C++, I would have thought you might be able to interpret.

Comment: So you want to make a list of **reference to macros**? Is it guaranteed that each macro is a `variable.member`?

Comment: Do you only need to read from them, or you need writing to them too?

Comment: @andymango I suppose that's only pseudocode.

Comment: "Faster" is subjective. It depends on the programmer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547352/c-cannot-take-address-of-bit-field

Comment: Yes it is only pseudocode. I will be writing the registers as well. The error is only "unexpected token [ ]", but List does the same. And by "faster" I really meant, less complex.

Comment: I am confused about what you want from these defines. It seems that each of the KP defines would be an address value to a register, yet you are testing whether each is equal to a number (1 in the above)?.

Comment: Yes, because with XC8, if I write this: LATBbits.B0 == 1, it will read the register LATBbits.B0 and compare it to 1. I could also write LATBbits.B0 = 1, where it would set its value to 1. But I want to encapsulate thses registers ADRESSES in more familiar name such as KP_ROW1. This code wouldn't work you are right. If I declared the variable type while I make the list, It would probably read to registers directly, but want I want, is to be able to REFER directly to the register. the ADRESS as you say.

Comment: C does not support classes. Before starting with bare-metal, learn the C language properly. There is nothing like "embedded C", just get a good C textbook, you can't learn the language by trial&error or obscure youtube videos or online "tutorials".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! 
It was not working because I was trying to get the adress of the bit instead of the register.... my bad. It should rather be:

```
#define KP_ROW LATB
```

And then add some bitmasks to write the pins I want.
Sorry for this beginner's error!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand what is desired here. I understand that you wish to read the values of 100 register in your program. You have to know their addresses. Then, you can create a series of macros:

```
#define REG1 0xabcd
#define REG2 0x1234
...
```

or whichever addresses. Then, create more macros to access the values directly:

```
#define REG1_VAL (*(volatile uint8_t *) REG1)
#define REG2_VAL (*(volatile uint8_t *) REG2)
...
```

Then you can write assignments such as REG1_VAL = 1 or tests such as REG1_VAL == 1. Otherwise, you can create macros that access their values through their addresses:

```
#define READ(reg) (*(volatile uint8_t *) reg)
```

Usage of the above to obtain a register value is then:

```
READ(REG1);
```

You could then allocate an array of 100 elements:

```
volatile uint8_t regs[100] = {REG1, REG2, ..., REG100};
```

and iterate through that array:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    if (READ(regs[i]) == 1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Note: These macros would need fine tuning to avoid subtle errors, but I hope they are still useful to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Usually, there are libraries online that already implement useful routines such as the above for popular microcontrollers. Then you don't have to deal with these kinds of details.

Comment: You are aware 100 bytes on a PIC12-18 is a massive waste of resources?

Comment: Yes, but if I need to call 100 registers what would you do? Directly call them? I feel it is gonna become more and more confusing, or hardly readable by my partners, I'm not the only one on the project

Comment: @PyThagoras You can save significant memory if the registers are in adjacent memory spaces. All you'd need in that case is a pointer to the first one and access the others by incrementing the pointer. It's essentially as if the array was predefined for you.